# Use one hot encoding and decision tree for a hybrid data set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

Here are some examples of my dataset:

```
price,city,color,model,function,name
میتسوبیشی اوتلندر,1396,200000,سفید,میرداماد,665000000
ب ام و,1386,120000,سفید صدفی,تهران,820000000
تویوتا لندکروز ,1386,14000,سفید,خیابان شهید بهشتی,1950000000
ام وی ام ,1385,0,مشکی,تهران,1290000000
پژو ,1399,0,سفید,تهران,310000000
```

I want to use the decision tree algorithm : name, function, model, color, city  as a test and guess the price as a result

How do I use one hot encoding can convert name, color, city to encoding and later along with the use Model, function as test input to DecisionTreeClassifier().fit() to guess the price?

If you have a better and faster method, I will be happy to introduce it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with scikit learn. I've added links of the API documentation of Scikitlearn and One hot encoding samples.

`from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder`

- [One hot encoding sample](https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd)
- [Scikit Learn Website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

  ```
   import pandas as pd


  df=pd.read_clipboard(sep=',') 


   from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
   from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


   labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
   df['price_cat'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['price'])
   df['model_cat'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['model'])
   df['function-cat'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['function'])

   enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')# passing bridge-types-cat column (label encoded values of bridge_types)
   enc_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df[['model_cat']]).toarray())
   enc_df.columns = enc.get_feature_names(['model'])

   df = df.join(enc_df)

   df
  ```

Note: You need to do labelencoder before Onehotencoder, because scikitlearn's OneHotEncoder doesn't work string categorical variables.

Comment: This is what I know I want to see using the data I put.